# AWS CLI access to S3 returns error 104

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

AWS reports that all their services are operating normally, but I get Error 104 'Connection reset by peer' on all my S3 requests via the AWS CLI.  Yesterday it was working fine.  Do you have any suggestions for how to fix this?

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.32 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 botocore/1.4.89

$ aws s3 ls s3://
('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

$ aws s3api list-buckets
('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Here is the list-buckets command with debugging info:

```
$ aws s3api list-buckets --debug
2016-12-21 09:25:11,926 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.11.32 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 botocore/1.4.89
2016-12-21 09:25:11,927 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['s3api', 'list-buckets', '--debug']
2016-12-21 09:25:11,927 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,927 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,929 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
2016-12-21 09:25:11,988 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.s3: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,988 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2016-12-21 09:25:11,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.s3api: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,992 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/waiters-2.json
2016-12-21 09:25:11,993 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict()
2016-12-21 09:25:11,994 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,994 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,994 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,996 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/paginators-1.json
2016-12-21 09:25:11,996 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,996 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:11,997 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:11,997 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.s3.list-buckets.cli-input-json: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,997 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.s3.list-buckets.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:11,997 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:11,997 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.s3api.list-buckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:11,998 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2016-12-21 09:25:11,998 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
2016-12-21 09:25:11,998 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2016-12-21 09:25:12,030 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2016-12-21 09:25:12,033 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,033 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,034 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2016-12-21 09:25:12,037 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2016-12-21 09:25:12,037 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=ListBuckets) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': '', 'url': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.11.32 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 botocore/1.4.89'}, 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'signing': {'bucket': None}, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'client_config': }, 'query_string': '', 'url_path': u'/', 'method': u'GET'}
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler >
2016-12-21 09:25:12,038 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-sign.s3.ListBuckets: calling handler 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,039 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using hmacv1 auth.
2016-12-21 09:25:12,039 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - HTTP request method: GET
2016-12-21 09:25:12,039 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
GET


Wed, 21 Dec 2016 14:25:12 GMT
/
2016-12-21 09:25:12,044 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: 
2016-12-21 09:25:12,044 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.amazonaws.com
2016-12-21 09:25:12,078 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 204, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: You should have definitely mentioned your usage of a VM here as well as any other "special" network configurations in place if any. At first glance I would have suspected a bare metal machine with potential network issues.

Answer (score 21):

I experienced this too, but when I specify the region where my S3 bucket reside, the problem solved.

```
aws s3 --region ap-southeast-1 cp file100Mb.zip s3://mybucket.domain.xyz/path/
```

You can try and let me know how it does for you.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it didn't work with region added to url, but works great with `--region` parameter.

Answer (score 12):

For me, I installed the awscli via the apt-get command (Ubuntu 16). It was working fine for us-east-1 region. But when I tried to upload files to different regions to a newly created bucket it started giving me this error. By removing the aws cli and installing via pip resolved this issue. It seems the version which is installed via apt-get is not updated for ubuntu 16.

```
sudo apt-get install pip
pip install awscli
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched my VM networking from "NAT" to "bridged" and S3 magically started working.  When it stopped working, I had not change anything manually; I hope VMware was not changing the network by itself.  But if you get error 104, check your network settings.

Comment: just a heads up to anyone that get here searching by the error, sometimes it's because you are trying to use a bucket that is not in the classic aws region, you can either wait a while or use an older bucket. ( here is a link to a better description https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/634#issuecomment-40778786 )